# Node.js: Jade Template with i18next and Bootstrap Glyphicon

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug, i18next

Trying Jade with node.js, express, twitter bootstrap and i18next I replaced within a file "index.jade"

```
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-flash
| Submit
```

with

```
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-flash
| = t('app.submit')
```

`app.submit` comes from an i18next compliant JSON file. In general i18next replacement work fine, also `app.submit` if used within a simple line like this:

```
label= t('app.submit')
```

I also tried different ways like `|= t('..` or `| =t('...`.

Does somebody has an idea where I should search for this problem or even has a solution?

Thanks in advance!
Rainer

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning! Quite simple, `|` stays for continuing next line. You can leave this. Means that ist working:

```
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-flash= t('app.submit')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility :

```
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-flash
| #{t('app.submit')}
```